# Function keeps doing the same thing

Tags: python, function, loops

This program suppose to find 1000 prime numbers and pack them into a list

Here's the code:

```
num = raw_input('enter a starting point')
primes = [2]
num = int(num)
def prime_count(num):

    if num % 2 == 0: #supposed to check if the number is divided by 2 evenly
        num = num +1 #if it is, then add 1 to that number and check again
        return num


    elif num % num == 0:
        primes.append(num) #supposed to add that prime to a list
        num = num + 1 #add 1 and check again
        return num


while len(primes) <= 999:
    prime_count(num)
```

So what actually happens when I run it:
it asks me raw_input and then goes to various things depending on what I choose as input:

- If I choose a prime, let's say 3, it runs and adds 999 of 3s to the list instead of adding it just one time and going on to try 4
- If I choose a non-prime, let's say 4, it just breaks, after that I can't even print out a list

What am i doing wrong?

UPDATE:
I fixed it, but when i run it with this i'm getting an error (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int')

```
number = raw_input('enter a starting point')
primes = [2]
number = int(number)
def prime_count(x):

    if x % 2 == 0: #supposed to check if the number is divided by 2 evenly
        number = x +1 #if it is, then add 1 to that number and check again
        return number



    else:
        for i in range(3, x-1):
            if x % i == 0:
                primes.append(x) #supposed to add that prime to a list
                number = x + 1 #add 1 and check again
                return number


while len(primes) <= 999:
    number = prime_count(number)
```

Comment: You seem to be not understanding the difference between local and global variables, or the way that function parameters and return values work. To help, I suggest you rename all of the variables outside of `prime_count`.

Comment: You need to learn about scoping rules in Python. `num` is being treated as a local variable in `prime_count`. What is the point of user input here, anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never using the return value from prime_count. Try this:

```
while len(primes) <= 999:
    num = prime_count(num)
```

You've set your self up for confusion by using the name  `num` as both a parameter  (also a local variable) inside of `prime_count`, and also as a global variable. Even though they have the same name, they are different variables, due to Python's rules for the scope of variables.

Also, `prime_count` is (probably unintentionally) leveraging the fact that `primes` is a global variable. Since you're not *assigning* to it, but rather just calling a method  (append), the code will work without using the `global` keyword.

However, your algorithm isn't even correct. `if num % num == 0` says *"if a number divided by itself has a remainder of zero"* which will *always* be true. This program will find a lot of "primes" that aren't primes.

Real Python programs do very little in the global scope; your current code is just asking for confusion.  I suggest you start with this template, and also do some reading of existing Python code.

```
def add_three(a_param):
    a_local_var = 3       # This is *different* than the one in main!
                          # Changes to this variable will *not* affect
                          # identically-named variables in other functions

    return a_local_var + a_param

def main():
    a_local_var = 2

    result = add_three(a_local_var)

    print result    # prints 5

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I think the error is what is already mentioned in the comments below the question and not what you point out here

Comment: I wrote one of those comments. His variable names do clash, but the code should function.

Comment: I don't see how this code should work without the variable clash. Without the variable clash the program would just test num % 2 == 0 and num % n == 0. That's not how a primetest works.

Comment: @Phidelux Yes, my edit just before your comment stated just that.